# Confirming biometric appointment availability before paying

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications

How can I check biometric appointment availability in Kolkata for a UK visa before paying? I am an Indian.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay first; then it will redirect you to the vfsglobal website where you can book a slot and upload the documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the visa application and pay the visa fees on UKVI website before you are directed to the VFS website to upload documents and schedule an appointment. So there is no way to check the availability before paying. From my experience (had my biometric appointment this Monday in Bangalore), the free appointments (without any extra VFS paid services) are available after 4-5 days from date of submission. The premium paid appointments are available after 1-2 days, but this may be pertinent only for Bangalore and my particular case. Hope this helps.